# Python create set of XML Dom elements

Tags: python, xml, dom, set, overloading

I am trying to create a python set of XML dom elements in order to remove duplicates. I parsed the elements using `xmldoc = minidom.parse('out.xml')` followed by `notelist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('note')` but when creating a set like so `noteset = set(notelist)` the set contains the same number of elements that the list contains. If I understand correctly it's because of the way `__eq__` and `__hash__` are defined for the DOM elements in notelist. How do I overload those functions?

Here's a sample of the XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notes>
    <note>
        <tag>Tag1</tag>
        <text>Note1</text>
        <dateTimeUtc>2015-04-05T18:14:13Z</dateTimeUtc>
        <textCursorPosition>183</textCursorPosition>
    </note>
    <note>
        <tag>Tag2</tag>
        <text>Note2</text>
        <dateTimeUtc>2015-04-05T18:09:05Z</dateTimeUtc>
        <textCursorPosition>504</textCursorPosition>
    </note>
    <note>
        <tag>Tag2</tag>
        <text>Note2</text>
        <dateTimeUtc>2015-04-05T18:09:05Z</dateTimeUtc>
        <textCursorPosition>504</textCursorPosition>
    </note>
</notes>
```

My aim is to output the same file but with the duplicate note "Note2" being included only once.

Comment: If, say, you are ultimately looking for the unique text values (strings) in the nodes, then just make a set of those.

Comment: well, but i wanna generate an xml file with the unique dom elements

Comment: So you want to preserve child nodes, attributes, etc.? That might indeed be tricky. Include some more details in the question like a sample input and output.

Comment: I added a sample input/output. The idea was to create a set of the DOM elements so that duplicates are removed then create an output xml file based on that set.

Comment: I think the simplest option is to make a dictionary where the keys are tuples of strings `(tag, text, dateTimeUtc, textCursorPosition)` and the values are the actual nodes. The dict will make the keys unique and a tuple of strings will hash and compare equality intuitively.